# estimate of infinite norm by $(p,q)$ norms

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $p$ and $q$ be conjugate exponents, i.e. $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Prove or disprove:
$$
\|f\|_\infty^2\le\|f\|_p\|f'\|_q
$$

I think this is true. I tried to prove it using integration by parts but did not succeed.

Comment: What if $f$ is constant?

Comment: You are right. It is false when f' is very small. Is there any way to add an additional condition to make the statement true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $f$ is defined on the real line and vanishes at infinity, then combining the fundamental theorem of calculus with Hölder's inequality yields $$|f(x)|^2\leqslant 2\max\left\{\left(\int_0^{\infty}|f(t)|^p\mathrm dt\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_0^{\infty}|f'(t)|^q\mathrm dt\right)^{1/q};
\left(\int_{-\infty}^0|f(t)|^p\mathrm dt\right)^{1/p}\left(
\int_{-\infty}^0|f'(t)|^q\mathrm dt\right)^{1/q}\right\}.$$
Indeed, we have $f(x)^2=2\int_{-\infty}^xf'(t)ft)\mathrm dt $ (this for $x\leqslant 0$) and a similar estimate for a positive $x$.

Comment: Could you please give more details? I started with writing $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f'(t) dt$, but did not know how to proceed. Also, if $f$ is the characteristic function of $[0,1]$, then it seems that the inequality is false.

Comment: I edited. The problem of the characteristic function of the unit interval is its derivative: it does exist in sense of distribution but it cannot be represented by a locally integrable function.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't see why $f(x)^2=2\int_{-\infty}^xf'(t)f(t) dt$.

Comment: It rests on the fact that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$ and the fact that the derivative of $f^2$ is $2f'f$.

Comment: Great! So this is a true statement for f being a Schwartz function or a distribution, right?

Comment: I agree for a Schwartz function, but I'm not sure what you mean for a distribution.